# GTA IV not using my Nvidia GPU

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-iv

I just got GTA IV for PC. I'm currently playing it on an Asus N550JK-DS71T. I can launch the game and start it up without any problems, save the fact that the game is using my integrated GPU instead of my dedicated GPU. I've tried almost everything: Nvidia Control Panel, running the game with the GPU etc. and I've searched the web for answers but I just can't find anything.

PC Specs:

- **OS:** Windows 8.1
- **CPU:** Intel Core i7-4700HQ
- **Integrated GPU:** Intel HD Graphics 4600
- **Dedicated GPU:** Nvidia GeForce GTX850
- **RAM:** 8GB

Comment: See possible solutions here: [How to use dedicated video card instead of onboard?](http://superuser.com/q/231446/10259) - and let us know how those worked.

Comment: Laptop or desktop. Laptop will require the 240v that came with it for higher graphics.